# c# WinForms: проблемы с вызовом конекстного меню после добавления Drag-Drop

Tags: c#, winforms

Проблема с запуском контекстного меню у объекта `TreeView` на форме. После того, как пользователь левой кнопкой выделил элемент в дереве, ему нужно два раза жать на правую кнопку мыши, чтобы появилось контекстное меню. Клиента это очень раздражает.

Проблема появилась после того, как `treeView` на форме стал использоваться, как источник данных в процедуре перетаскивания мышью Drag-Drop, реализованными стандартными средствами MicroSoft.

В обработчик нажатия был добавлен следующий код:

```
private void treeView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        TreeNode node = treeView.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);

        if (node != null)
        {
            // ... некоторые предварительные вычисления, 
            // не влияющие на элементы формы, а меняющие Tag у node

            //Проблемы появились после добавления этой стандартной функции от MicroSoft
            treeView.DoDragDrop(node, DragDropEffects.Copy); 

            //Это старый код, который должен остаться и при котором все работало
            treeView.SelectedNode = node;
        }
    }
}
```

Сам Drag-Drop отрабатывается без проблем.

Если важно, то на `treeView_AfterSelect` реализован обработчик, заполняющий элементы формы информацией

```
private void treeView_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode currentNode = treeView.SelectedNode;
    if (currentNode != null)
    {
        FillAll(currentNode);
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста как решить эту проблему без реализации собственного Drag-Drop, либо как объяснить клиенту, что это не баг в реализации `DoDragDrop()` MicroSoft-ом, а фича.

Детальное изучение это редкого явления показало, что для останова процедуры `DoDragDrop()` недостаточно просто отпустить левую кнопку мыши. Обработчик `treeView_MouseUp()` в случае использования стандартного `DoDragDrop()` на него не отзывается.

UpDate от 26.12.2016: По запросу добавляю код, обрабатывающий события процедуры DragDrop:

1) На событие DragEnter для контрола `ListBox lstBxForSearch;` , который является приемником DragDrop повешен следующий обработчик:

```
private void lstBxForSearch_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // Предварительно сбрасываем флаг допустимости использования контрола lstBxForSearch,
    // как приемника процедуры DragDop
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;

    // Устанавливаем этот флаг, если объект, который тянем, может быть принят 
    // контролом lstBxForSearch, то есть источником служит контрол treeView 
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(TreeNode)))
    {
        TreeNode node = e.Data.GetData(typeof(TreeNode)) as TreeNode;
        if (node != null && node.TreeView == treeView)
        {
            //Допустимый источник 
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
    }
}
```

2) На событие DragDrop для `ListBox lstBxForSearch;` повешен такой обработчик:

```
private void lstBxForSearch_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    //Анализируем, что принесли на мыше
    TreeNode node = e.Data.GetData(typeof(TreeNode)) as TreeNode;
    if (node == null) 
        return;
    addPlantToSearchList(node);
}
```

и соответственно

```
private void addPlantToSearchList(TreeNode currentNode)
{
    PlantExtendTag tg = currentNode.Tag as PlantExtendTag;
    if (tg == null) 
        return;

    MyDS.PlantShort_ViewRow plantRow = tg.PlantRow;

    if ((TacsonomyLeve)plantRow.LevelNum == TacsonomyLeve.Kind)
    {
        lstBxPlantsForSearch.Items.Add(new NameId(plantRow.Id, currentNode.Text));
    }
    else
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel.Text = "Расширенный поиск предусмотрен только по пересечению видов";
    }
}
```

Comment: не смог воспроизвести проблему. Контекстное меню нормально вызывается с одного правого клика, после DragDrop. Все события отрабатывают. Скорее всего ошибка в каком-то фрагменте, который вы не привели в вопросе.

Comment: Событие AterSelect и заполнение ноды тут ни причем. Как у вас вызывается меню, может проблема там? добавьте этот фрагмент. Ну и код обработки событий DragXXX тоже не помешает.

Comment: rdorn, огромное спасибо  за участие в моей проблеме. Дело в том,что если хотя бы чуть-чуть пошевелить мышью - проблема исчезает. Она имеет место, если мышь остается неподвижной. Тогда для вызова контекстного меню нужно два раз нажимать на правую кнопку. Складывается ощущение, что разработчик DoDragDrop() забыл, что процедуру нужно прекращать  по _MouseUp(), даже когда мышь неподвижна. Контекстное меню просто привязано к trееView, через проперти. Код обработки событий DragXXX  сейчас выложу.

Comment: Код добавил. Ну и на всякий случай, чтобы, была полная информация - контекстное меню добавляется штатным дизайнером форм в VisualStudio.

Comment: ок, при отсутствии перемещений мышки баг с правым кликом подтверждаю, причем иногда требуется больше двух кликов, очевидно количество кликов зависит от погоды на венере...

Comment: Нашел!!! Родной костыль от микрософт специально для TreeView

Comment: Сайт не для оценки знаний, а поиска информации и взаимопомощи. Если есть что сказать и хватит тебе духу, то можно поговорить по скайпу. Я 1С-разработчик и самостоятельно изучаю С#. Если есть, что написать по делу - пиши, можешь дать совет - дай, но по моему ты занимаешься чем-то другим.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У `TreeView` есть специальное событие [**TreeView.ItemDrag**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.itemdrag(v=vs.110).aspx). Это событие срабатывает, когда после мы начинаем тянуть элемент с зажатой клавишей мыши (можно настроить какой именно клавишей). При обычном клике оно не срабатывает. Подписываемся на него, и в нем начинаем процедуру перетаскивания. Например так:

```
private void treeView1_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        treeView1.DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
}
```

Теперь можно убрать вызов `DoDragDrop` из обработчика `MouseDown` и забыть про багофичу с правым кликом.

---

Это не единственный сюрприз от `DoDragDrop`. После его активации перестают обрабатываться все события мыши до его завершения. Скорее всего это связано с тем, что события мыши передаются оконному менеджеру, а не окну вашей программы, т.к. DragDrop может перетаскивать объекты между программами, а для этого нужен внешний контекст. Но глубоко в WinAPI я не копал, так что пожалуй это не плохая тема для отдельного [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/608268/198316).

Comment: Оно !!!! Сегодня очень удачный день :). Огромное Вам спасибо за помощь

Comment: Раз автор принял ответ, получайте следом и награду )