# Как бороться с Drag'N'Drop от Microsoft

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

В процессе поиска решения для [**этого**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/600943/198316) вопроса, появился новый вопрос.

У контролов WinForms для работы с Drag'n'Drop в .NET предусмотрено несколько типовых событий и метод [DoDragDrop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop(v=vs.110).aspx).

Но есть несколько проблем связанных с ними. Если мы активируем `DoDragDrop` по событию `MouseDown`, то до завершения процесса перетаскивания окно нашей программы не получает события мыши, но получает события связанные с процедурой перетаскивания. Пока вроде все логично, но если после активации перетаскивания объекта мышь не перемещается, то процедура завершается не сразу, а с неопределенным таймаутом, и в это время события мыши не передаются нашему окну, что собственно и вызвало проблему описанную в вопросе по ссылке выше.

Для `TreeView` и `ListView` оказалось есть решение из коробки - событие `ItemDrag`, но для других контролов, которые потенциально могли бы стать источником для Drag'n'Drop, такого решения не предусмотрено.

Пока в голову пришло только одно решение:

1. По событию `MouseDown` поднимать флаг о возможном начале перетаскивания и запоминать потенциальный объект перетаскивания в приватных полях формы.
2. По событию `MouseMove` проверять флаг и состояние клавиш мыши, и если заданные условия выполнены, вызвать метод `DoDragDrop` в параметры которого передать предварительно сохраненный объект в качестве данных для перетаскивания. После этого сбросить флаг.

Но мне почему-то кажется что это костыль, потому что в зависимости от того, что и откуда мы собираемся перетаскивать, код будет различаться и его придется дублировать для каждой формы, в которой потребуется такой функционал.

Собственно вопрос, правильно ли я понимаю, что процесс перетаскивания выполняется в контексте операционной системы, а не отдельных программ, для обеспечения возможности перетаскивания объектов между программами? Если предположение верное, то существует ли решение обойти перечисленные проблемы более гибко, без строительства велосипедов из костылей? Если мое предположение не верно - то в ответе хотелось бы увидеть как это работает на самом деле.

Вопрос адресован скорее знатока WinAPI, но решение хотелось бы получить в контексте C#. В принципе, мне, подойдет любое решение, которое можно будет адаптировать для .NET, если оно будет лучше уже изложенного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Буду рассуждать логически: У тебя не так уж много контролов, которые могут принимать в себя перетаскиваемый обьект. Уверен, их на форме от силы 1-3.

Так почему бы не посмотреть как реализован `ItemDrag` в `TreeView` и `ListView` (благо, соурсы [легко гуглятся по запросу "treeview source code"](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/TreeView@cs/1305376/TreeView@cs)) и не реализовать нужный тебе ItemDrag ивент в нужных контролах путем наследования и последующего расширения возможностей?

- Код будет, скорее всего, практически, идентичным.(я имею ввиду код `ItemDrag` для всех наследников оригинальных класов)
- Код твоей программы не будет замусориватся лишними флагами и методами. Все будет все так же читабельно, как если бы эти методы там были из коробки :)

Comment: Кроме контролов, которые могут принимать принимаемый объект, на форме есть еще куча других контролллов, например slider-ы, которые должны реагировать, когда перетаскиваемый объект находится над ними. Написать свой DragDrop не проблема, проблема в том, что некоторые компоненты этого механизма затрагивают слишком много контролов. Очевидно, что это все реализуемо в общем виде через сообщения, да беда в том, что в с# менеджер сообщений слишком глубоко закопан.

Comment: Подсмотреть было первой мыслью, только это все в нативном коде, а исходники доступны только для оболочки https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TreeView.cs,2473. Про наследование думал, но пока больше склоняюсь к универсальному декоратору, правда еще не пробовал в коде, времени пока нет.

Comment: Да и проблема, в общем то, не с приемом перетаскиваемого, а с началом перетаскивания "если после активации перетаскивания объекта мышь не перемещается, то процедура завершается не сразу, а с неопределенным таймаутом".

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов не нужно переписывать DrugNDrop, он нормально работает, за исключением бага с задержкой завершения перетаскивания если мышь неподвижна.

Comment: "...не нужно переписывать DrugNDrop.." - совершенно согласен, но мне показалось, что фактически именно это в той или иной форме  предлагают сделать оба автора данных пока ответов :).

Comment: Нее, я предлагаю не это. Я предлагаю просто дополнить еще одним ивентом нужные контролы. Где у меня написано переписывать все ивенты DrugNDrop-а с нуля?

Comment: @Andrew, добавить то можно, но только не факт, что контрол будет на него отзываться. Вы посмотрите мой исходный вопрос (на него есть ссылка), в процессе ответа на который rdorn более широко взглянул на проблему и у него возник этот более общий вопрос. Беда в том, что менеджер сообщений слишком глубоко закопан внутрь операционной системы. Хотелось бы понять как можно повлиять на перехват сообщений в этом случае.

Comment: Спасибо, натолкнули на интересную мысль, попробую отпишусь подробно, после завершения конкурса.

Comment: В общем то почти по вашему ответу и получилось. Реализовал производный от Panel контрол, что позволило не страдать при необходимости таскать дочерние контролы с панели на панель через драг-дроп.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы обернул контролы, в которых необходимо задействовать Drag'n'Drop в следующую оболочку :

- Описать поле, в котором находится объект. Относительно этого объекта,
  производить рефреш, если его заменили другим.
- Описать метод    GetInnerType() - определение типа объекта который
  может принять в    себя контрол.
- Ну и описать относительно контролов    с оболочкой    MouseDown и
  MouseUp, с проверкой поля IsDragging и    DragContainer -    где
  находится текущий объект.
- Собственно на    MouseUp определять тип       объекта относительно
  DragContainer и    сверять с GetInnerType    объекта    который
  принимает в себя этот    объект, ну и принимать    или не принимать внутрь себя объект.

Пока такие мысли. Оборачивать контрол..

Comment: спасибо за участие, но пожалуйста, перечитайте вопрос внимательнее, проблема совсем в другом. В целом технология работает как нужно из коробки, но есть один досадный баг, который и нужно красиво обойти.