# Drag'n'Drop с treeview на форму

Tags: c#, winforms

нужно сделать перетягивание названия узла дерева на bandedgridview. пока что сделал такое, что еще нужно добавить\изменить?

```
  private void NodeClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        node = ((TreeView)sender).SelectedNode;
        Position = new Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y);

    }

    private void tv_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode node = tv.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);
        if (node != null)
        {
            tv.SelectedNode = node;
            selectDeptId = Convert.ToInt32(node.Name);
        }

    }

    private void tv_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            DoDragDrop(Department.Item(mApp, selectDeptId.Value, Date), DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }
```

Comment: это работает? Если работает, то о чем вопрос? Если не работает, то что именно не работает?

Comment: Для начала я бы использовал событие `TreeView.ItemDrag` для активации drag'n'drop, чтобы потом не лечить [такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/600943/198316). В остальном присоединяюсь к tym32167 - в чем собственно вопрос? Очевидно, что нужно дописать обработку получения перетаскиваемого названия.